# Cannot create directory: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, vps, git

I'm trying for the first time to set up GIT on a VPS following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps). Part of the instructions are:

```
cd /var
mkdir repo && cd repo
mkdir site.git && cd site.git
git init --bare
```

However, on `mkdir repo` I get `cannot create directory ‘repo’: Permission denied`. I'm logged into the VPS as a user with sudo rights. How can I find out the cause of the problem? I'm really new to this so am not sure what to report here.

**Update:** After solving the above by adding `sudo` to the command, I got a permission error on `git push live master`:

```
Counting objects: 709, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (665/665), done.
Writing objects: 100% (709/709), 103.57 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 709 (delta 368), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/var/repo/site.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To ssh://username@VPS_IP_ADRES/var/repo/site.git
 ! [remote rejected] 3.7-advanced-testing -> 3.7-advanced-testing (unpacker error)
etc.
```

I did skip a few steps of the tutorial because I already have GIT completely set up in Cloud9IDE (which I use for writing my app). This works and I can push to Heroku, which I now am trying to replace with a VPS. So what I have done from a situation with a working GIT: I did the four steps mentioned above, while logged into the VPS as superuser. Then, while logged in at Cloud9, I did `git remote add live ssh://username@VPS_IP_ADRES/var/repo/site.git`. And then `git push -u live --all`, which gave me the errors above. Any idea about there cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is assuming you have superuser rights, so just use `sudo su` before you start running commands, or insert `sudo` before all the commands that require elevation.

Comment: Thanks William, that worked: `sudo mkdir repo`. Im going to read up on what it means exactly to have superuser rights.

Comment: I was hoping to ask a follow up question, which I added to my OP (see update).

Comment: Did you log in through SSH as a normal user or as root?

Comment: Actually, after the first four steps I logged out from the VPS. I am then still logged in in Cloud9. In Cloud9 I did: `git remote add live ssh://username@VPS_IP_ADRES/var/repo/site.git` and `git push -u live --all`.

Comment: I'd say either SSH in as root, or instead of using `/var` stick the repo in the Cloud9 home directory (`/home/Cloud9/var/repo` for example). You're getting errors because the Cloud9 user doesn't have permission to modify subdirectories in `/var`.

Comment: I think I might be completely misunderstanding what I am doing. Current situation: I'm using GIT and Bitbucket succesfully in Cloud 9. I can push new versions to GIT, etc. I can also push the master to Heroku. I now created `/var/repo/site.git` in the assumption that that's where you should push your app to when you want to deploy on the VPS. Then, when in Cloud9, I want to push the latest version to the VPS.

Comment: With `git remote add live ssh://marty@IPADRES/var/repo/site.git` I specify where Cloud9 can find the location where to push to when it should push to the VPS. And `git push -u live --all` actually pushes it to that location.
Now I'm confused since you give as an option to create a folder in Cloud9, which would have nothing to do with way I'm aiming at, namely deploying the app to the VPS. Could you perhaps explain? Have I perhaps misunderstood what those step really do?

Comment: So since you're logging in through SSH as marty, you should be able to use `/home/marty/repo` or `/home/marty/var/repo` for the location of the repo. Otherwise you can mess around with permissions to make it so that the user marty can write to `/var/repo` since the issue is that the user that's trying to create files doesn't have permission to modify `/var/repo`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I created a new folder in `/home/username/` as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

you need root privilege so you have to add sudo :

```
cd /var
sudo mkdir repo && cd repo
sudo mkdir site.git && cd site.git
sudo git init --bare
```